# how to style listpickeritem windows phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, styles

can someone tell me how to style listpicker elements on fullscreen mode?

this is my code in page xaml:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker FullModeItemTemplate="{Binding lpkFullItemTemplate}"
                                 ItemTemplate="{Binding lpkItemTemplate}"
                                x:Name="people"/>
```

the templates are:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding people_list}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="lpkFullItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding people_list}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

i also want to know if there's a way to prevent the listpicker go in full mode. i've tried to set the ItemCountThreshold proprety but i found out that is private in wp8 sdk

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Test it

```
<toolkit:ListPicker>
        <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:Name="ListPickerFullItemTemplate">
                <TextBlock FontSize="32" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

Comment: when you say " it don't work".It is for binding or for template?
I think template work, don't forget to set mode property when you bind Text property in textblock.(mode=TwoWay)

Comment: the binding work, i can see the elements declared in c# code in the listpicker and i can select them. the listpicker works perfectly, but i can't style it (= can't change fontsize, color or anything)

Comment: if you want to change style in listpickeritem look http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.visualstate.aspx for information and for issue it's here http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-customize-the-listpicker-selected-item

Comment: sorry i can't understand where to place the new template (for example the one suggested on phonegeek), also i don't want to change a single state only the item's fontsize, do i have to redefine the entire style?

Comment: This style make place in ressource page.TargetType property is the name of your listBox.And you need juste to define what you want, i think you just need to define state selected unselected.You can use blend for this.http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc296245(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: For fast and easy methode --> go to blend right click on list box --> edit itemtemplatecontainer --> edit current you have acces to item and now do what you want :)

Comment: if i place the template in my code and add the style to the listpicker i  got an exception

@user2598451 on blend "edit current" it's disabled. i'm able to ccreate another but i can't any option for the fontsize